# Closing questions about how to improve writing

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

Tips on improving one's English are off-topic for the site. I wanted to make sure that people feel the same way about the following writing related questions that RegDwight brought to my attention:

> ...we do have quite a few (open) questions about improving *writing* skills: [Recommended books on writing well](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/8068/), [Tips and Tricks to Become a Better Writer](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/4079/), [Which is the best way to improve your writing skills](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/5744/), and even [Advices and tips for writing tutorial](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7207/). I am not sure if any or all of them would be a better fit for Writers.SE, but right now, they're all here, and they're all open.

If you look at the answers, you can see why we would want these to be off-topic. There are few answers and those that are there are subjective and chatty.

If I had noticed them right when they were asked, I almost certainly would have closed them.  I was going to close them now, but I noticed that there were very few votes to close. In fact, one question was voted to 6 and the other was voted up to 9 with 5 favorites. This really surprises me.

I personally feel that these sorts of questions do not fit in with EL&U: they aren't really about language usage itself, they are too subjective, and in some cases they don't really seem to have a clear answer (subjective or not).

As I said, the only thing that stopped me from immediately deleting these questions was the lack of downvotes and votes to close; these sorts of questions are off-topic, aren't they?

Comment: Based on comments in Chat, and comments here, and the existence of writers.SE, I feel confident in going ahead and closing these questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer such questions to http://writers.stackexchange.com -- which, quite frankly, desperately needs our help to survive.

Comment: Can they be migrated? (I mean, manually, I know there is no readily-available migration path as Writers is still in Beta.) It would be a pity to just close them here and hope that they get reposted by the OP, which they probably won't.

Comment: Okay everyone, we now have a migration path to Writers, see the [update here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/600/extend-the-list-of-se-sites-presented-when-a-question-is-being-closed-as-off-topi/607#607)

Answer (score 0):

I agree, every question that doesn't directly asks about an English word, a phrase, or a sentence should be closed as off-topic. I include in the list also the question I asked about the pronunciation and the differences between the pronunciation of an adult and a teenager.

Comment: I don't know which exact question you mean, but questions about pronunciations and language usage in different populations have generally been considered on-topic.